# How to compare version numbers in gradle?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, version

I need to use a different Gradle plugin version dependening the Gradle version. How can I compare a version in Gradle? The variable gradle.gradleVersion is a string and can't good compare. The follow does not work if the minor version has only one digit.

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
     def ver = gradle.gradleVersion >= '2.12' ? '+' : '1.5.+'
     classpath group: 'de.inetsoftware', name: 'SetupBuilder', version: ver
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The class VersionNumber is the trick:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
     def ver = VersionNumber.parse( gradle.gradleVersion ) >= VersionNumber.parse( '2.12' ) ? '+' : '1.5.+'
     classpath group: 'de.inetsoftware', name: 'SetupBuilder', version: ver
  }
}
```

*Note:* `VersionNumber` is deprecated in Gradle 7 and is being removed from Gradle 8. There is no public replacement (it was never meant to be used outside of Gradle internal code). See docs.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/util/VersionNumber.html

Comment: VersionNumber looks like a dependency, and running gradle 5 this gives me the error `Could not get unknown property 'VersonNumber'`. Where can we find this dependency?

Comment: @JoshuaNelson - I think you just spelled `Version` wrong (you have `Verson` - missing the **i** in your comment).  I believe it is included in gradle.

Comment: Add `import org.gradle.util.VersionNumber` to fix the `Could not get unknown property 'VersionNumber'`

Comment: @Samuel-Neff Currently the class exists in the repository: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/util/internal/VersionNumber.java Why you think it is removed?

Comment: @Horcrux7 Two reasons. (1) it is in the `internal.*` package mean it's an internal implementation detail to Gradle and thus should not be used as there is no guarantee it will exist across versions. (2) the docs specifically say it is GOING TO BE removed, not already has been. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/util/VersionNumber.html.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I see my mistake with the two packages. Although I do not understand why such functions are removed. Fortunately, the world has moved on. Java has since version 9 the class java.lang.Runtime.Version. I can expect which will use Gradle 8 will also use Java 9 or higher.

Comment: deprecated in gradle 9.x